# Unable to save Razorpay Webhook Data received using ASP.NET C# Web Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webhooks, razorpay

I am trying to save the POST data received from Razorpay webhook to my SQL server. But I couldnt. I am unable to figure out the problem, Please help me out.

I am New in Webhook.

Below is my Page that Webhook gives response:

Successpage.aspx.cs Code:

````
using System;
using Razorpay.Api;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

public partial class Razorpay_Successpage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string documentContents;
        //To Capture RAW JSON posted
        using (Stream receiveStream = Request.InputStream)
        {
            using (StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                documentContents = readStream.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }

        Response.Write(documentContents);

        //To Capture Signature

        var RazorpaySignature = Request.Headers["X-Razorpay-Signature"];

        Response.Write(RazorpaySignature);
        //Response.Write(ReqHeader);```
    }
}
````

Above code prints only standard razorpay response sent on your checkout callback url.

I want to print other data that webhook gives so please help me about that.

Answer (score 1):

After getting the document contents, I tried in this way in order to get the data:

```
var details = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(documentContents);
var data = details["payload"];
var payment = data["payment"];
var entity = payment["entity"];
string OrderId = entity["order_id"].ToString();
string  paymentstatus = entity["status"].ToString();
```

This way I got the `order_id` and payment status in local variables, which I saved to database. Hope this helps you!